# Can msbuild unlock locked dlls during build time so avoid hitting "Cannot access the file because it is used by another process"?

Tags: .net, msbuild

Is there any possibility to allow msbuild unlock locked dlls during the build time.

e.g. to avoid hitting "The process cannot access the file X because it is being used by another process"?

This is really painful for huge projects, so something like this would be cool enough (instead of me doing manually unlocking them using e.g. LockHunter).

I've been hitting this when I had opened a specific project within VS, so I was building main project from a console (it cannot be opened in VS due its size)... also I've hit it also with same error message and when I opened file using LockHunter it says noone is locking, but msbuild failed during buildtime just because of this file.

Comment: You can add your own custom tasks... Sounds like extremely bad idea to have as part of MSBuild default tasks... You may want to figure out first what locks the files - something in the build itself or you just debugging code in some other process/IIS running... and update the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the intention was to get the clean build, which will be later deployed, so I got your point, shoud've have posted my intention in the thread.

Comment: hmm. I usually can build my solutions using msbuild while these same solutions are opened in VS. I feel, something else is going on. Is your project is a web project that is currently being served by a IIS pool?

Comment: @T.S. Nope it's proj file including all kinds of csproj, vcproj , and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. MS build can't do this. But since you must run `msbuild` command from a `batch` or `PS` script, you can add an action to this script, before msbuild command, to do file unlocking.

```
#REM here goes your command to unlock files
msbuld mysolution.sln  . . . . .
```

Comment: @luka032 Unfortunately, you have not provided your circumstance under which you have this issue. We might give you more suggestions

Comment: provided some info in the Q